# What is "ON M6C 1A1" in this address?

Tags: usage

I came across a Canadian address, part of which is not familiar to me. What does the bold part mean?

> 513 St Clair Ave W, Toronto, **ON M6C 1A1**

Comment: I'm not a regular here, but this appears off topic to me.

Comment: Probably you're right. Maybe better to be at ELU or Writers?

Comment: By the way, I enjoyed Feynman's quote on your profile @Beta-decay.

Comment: But frankly, it isn't technically related to English. At a stab, I'd say it's more suitable on a Geography SE site. But parkgatedev is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better on the Geography.SE site.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be what you are looking for:

**Street:** 513 Clair Avenue West

**City:** Toronto

***Province:*** Ontario (ON)

***Postcode:*** M6C 1A1